# Unable to mount new Synology DS918+

Tags: mount, samba, nfs

I have several Synology DS918+ which I can mount fine with:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/my_folder -o username=xxx,password='xxx',uid=1000,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 /my_local_folder
```

I have purchased a new DS918+ which I am having trouble mounting.

The new Synology OS appears not to allow NFS v1, but I'm unable to mount using either of these commands:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/my_folder -o username=xxx,password='xxx',uid=1000,sec=ntlm,vers=2.1 /my_local_folder

sudo mount -o username=xxx,password='xxx',uid=1000,sec=ntlm,vers=2.1 //x.x.x.x/my_folder /my_local_folder
```

These both fail with

```
mount: /my_local_folder: special device //x.x.x.x/my_folder does not exist
```

If I change the vers back to =1.0, I get

```
mount: /my_local_folder: special device //x.x.x.x/my_folder read only
```

I can ping the IP fine and connect to the Synology OS through a web site at x.x.x.x:5000

I have both NFS and SMB enabled in the File Services section of the Control Panel

I have added the "xxx" username with read and write priviledges.

I have a shared folder called "my_folder" on the NAS.

**EDIT**

I have changed uid to equal "xxx" as per an answer elsewhere, and installed SMBClient, but now get this:

```
mount: /my_local_folder: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.
```

**EDIT 2**

After installing cifs-utils, and returning to uid=1000, I get

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Have you tried to mount your Synology NAS using an fstab entry instead? I mount a couple of SAMBA shares in my Synology DS220j successfully (having first created the mount point directory) with the following (example) line: //192.168.1.117/video /media/NAS/video cifs username=xxxxx,password=xxxxxxxxx,rw,uid=1000,gid=500 The ip address is fixed in the router. I'm on 20.04.04 with the current kernel all up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never stated which version of Ubuntu you are using - actually, what version of the Linux kernel you are using.

If you are running with a Linux kernel that is at version 4.13.5 or greater the server and client will negotiate the highest possible value for "vers" automatically starting with vers 2.1.

So remove sec=ntlm and vers=2.1 from your mount statement and let the kernel handle this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/my_folder -o username=xxx,password='xxx,uid=1000 /my_local_folder
```

Comment: That was it - thank you greatly.